# Mocha: Promises timing out no matter the time limit

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, mocha.js

I'm working on an interview project for which I have to add an endpoint that lets me POST an array of products (listings) and it should create them (**MongoDB + Mongoose**) or update them accordingly. The problem is I'm clearly not dealing with Promises properly and I'm getting a timeout on my test.
Here's the spec:

```
    it.only('should create listings or update them if they already exist, incrementing the quantity with the difference ' +
      'between the current sold_quantity and the initial_sold_quantity', (done) => {
      var iPhone = { ... };
      var samsung = { ... };
      request(app).post('/listings/myEndpoint').send([iPhone, samsung]).expect(200, {
        created: 1,
        updated: 1
      }, done);
    });
```

```
exports.myEndpoint = (req, res) => {
  var listings = req.body;
  var created, updated = 0;

  listings.forEach(reqListing => {
    Listing.findOne({ listing_id: reqListing.listing_id })
      .then(foundListing => {
        if (!foundListing) {
          var newListing = reqListing;
          newListing.initial_sold_quantity = newListing.sold_quantity;
          Listing.create(newListing);
          created++;
        } else {
          var newQuantity = reqListing.sold_quantity - foundListing._doc.initial_sold_quantity;
          if (foundListing._doc.quantity != newQuantity) {
            foundListing._doc.quantity = newQuantity;
            foundListing.save();
            updated++;
          }
        }
      });
      return {
        created: created,
        updated: updated
      };
  });
};
```

**THINGS I'VE TRIED:**

1. Giving it more time. I tried changing the default timeout for Mocha tests but it doesn't really matter if it's 2 seconds or 20, it'll still timeout.
2. Isolating the update vs the creation. Really doesn't matter either if I'm only updating a product or if I'm only creating one, it'll still timeout.
3. Removing the logic. As far as I've checked it doesn't really matter what happens inside the if/else blocks because it'll still give me a timeout. So even if the code looks like this:

```
exports.myEndpoint = (req, res) => {
  var listings = req.body;
  var created, updated = 0;

  listings.forEach(reqListing => {
    Listing.findOne({ listing_id: reqListing.listing_id })
      .then(foundListing => {
        if (!foundListing) {
          console.log("creating");
        } else {
          console.log("updating");
        }
      });
      return {
        created: created,
        updated: updated
      };
  });
};
```

it'll still timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking some questions in the Nodeiflux Discord server I managed to find a solution, maybe not the prettiest because it doesn't make use of async/await but I'm not supposed to change the style of the project too much so I'll leave it without async/await.

First, the silly problem which came after fixing the post's question:

```
var created = 0, updated = 0;
```

instead of not initializing `created`.

Second, making use of forEach with Promises inside didn't make too much sense because it would discard whatever was returning inside so I put the return outside the forEach clause and changed the forEach iteration for a map instead. I also made use of Promise.all() to get all promises to resolve before returning:

```
exports.upsert = (req, res) => {
  var listings = req.body;
  var created = 0, updated = 0;
  var allowedArrayLength = 50;
  return Promise.all(listings.map(reqListing =>
    Listing.findOne({
        listing_id: reqListing.listing_id
      })
      .then(foundListing => {
        if (!foundListing) {
          createListing(reqListing);
          created++;
        } else {
          var prevQuantity = foundListing.quantity;
          if (updateListing(reqListing, foundListing).quantity > prevQuantity) {
            updated++;
          }
        }
      })
  )).then(() => ({ created: created, updated: updated }));
};
```